# How to insert delimiter into text that is in a specific format

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am currently using Microsoft Excel 2011 for Mac. I am trying to separate data in the following format with delimiters. So far I have not been able to come up with a practical solution. Can anyone provide me with one?

The text is in the format below.

> WPD0114
>
> ALC0414
>
> CBC0515
>
> IUC0515
>
> IEI1216

I would like the text to look like this.

> WPD,01,14
>
> ALC,04,14
>
> CBC,05,15
>
> IUC,05,15
>
> IEI,12,16

I apologise if a similar answer has been provided previously, but I have not been able to find a working solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split your strings up using LEFT(), MID() and RIGHT() and concatenate with commas.

```
=LEFT(A1,3)&","&MID(A1,4,2)&","&RIGHT(A1,2)
```

Comment: This is the easiest way to do this that I can think of, assuming the text length is always the same. If you were to only need to insert one character, I'd suggest `=replace(A1,3,0,",")` and if you were trying to actually replace, I'd say nested `substitute` functions. This is the answer for this scenario.

Comment: Never thought of doing a `replace()` with 0 for the `Num_chars` argument. Very clever!